# Cloudflare API -- rec_load_all

Tags: python, dns, cloudflare

I am trying to use the [Cloudlfare API](https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html#s5.2) to make a python script that acts as a sort of Dynamic DNS, as such it should update the IP stored for my `A` record to my current external IP, every X minutes.

So far, I have managed to get my IP from `http://api.ipify.org/` and the script collects my IP from that everytime it tries to update the DNS IP. The problem is the cloudflare API requires the DNS entry ID, and it says that you can get that from the `rec_load_all` call. I am able to make this but I have no idea how to get anything from the response, since all I can get is `<Response [200]>` whenever I try to see what it sent back, I need to access the ID of the main entry, but I don't know even slightly how to.

---

It should be noted, I have tried researching this, but with no success and so ended up here. This wall has been in my way for the past 3-4 days.

Comment: I have found the solution and now have it auto updating the the ip if it changes, I had used the module to create my own url shortener in python, I just copied some code over, and tweked and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

CloudFlare provide a port of ddclient that includes support for using the CloudFlare dynamic DNS updating system. Installing it over building your own system might save you some time. You can find it here: https://www.cloudflare.com/resources-downloads

Turning more directly to your question, [when you use `rec_load_all`](https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html#s3.3), it will list all records as responses, each with a `rec_id`. The [CloudFlare API documentation](https://www.cloudflare.com/docs/client-api.html) contains some cURL examples which you might find helpful. In addition to this there are API wrappers for it in pretty much every common language, if you look around on GitHub for them.